# which column in matlab selforgmap output corresponds to which neuron of the SOM map

Tags: matlab, som

I used selforgmap for pattern recognition. After training finished i calculated the network's output of the whole data and I got a logical matrix.

I want know how selforgmap:

1- numbers the neurons (i mean from 1 to N, while N equals the total number of neurons)
2-

Here is my map

```
     1      O------O
          /      / 
     0  O------O
       0  0.5  1  1.5
```

the output looks like this (after transpose)

1   0   0   0

0   1   0   0

1   0   0   0

1   0   0   0

0   0   1   0

0   1   0   0

0   0   1   0

0   0   1   0

i want know which column in output corresponds to which neuron of the map

Answer (score 1):

Selforgmap in MATLAB starts the numbering from the bottom left. For your example, the neurons are labeled:

3 - 4
 /   /
1   2

You can use the

`vec2ind(output)`

command to associate the output with the neuron to which the corresponding input has been assigned.